# Part Marking ID assistance - 4E30

Tags: integrated-circuit, markings

I'm having trouble figuring out the identity of this QFN-32 packaged component.  I can tell you it has a crystal attached so it's some king of embedded device.  I doubt it's an FPGA because it also has a native USB phy connection (D-/D+).  It also has a SPI flash device connected.  The minimal part marking makes me think it's some obscure brand or a counterfeit imitation of something else.  Thanks[image]

Comment: That’s how they protect their IP you are trying to steal. Use a microscope and bright light. That works.

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 Are you suggesting they've coated the component? And that I can possibly see through it with a bright enough light and a microscope?  This image was gathered using a fairly bright light and a crappy digital microscope.

Comment: It was sanded off but I can see the characters. Using edge lighting and a 10x optic lens on eyeball works or with mobile cam

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this is a high-speed USB to Ethernet bridge chip.

I found this part in a USB high speed extender ([www.tripplite.com](http://www.tripplite.com) B203-104-PNP), which consists of a "transmit" module and a "receive" module connected via an Ethernet cable up to 50m long.  Both modules use this same chip.

The transmit module converts high speed USB from your computer to Ethernet. (I'm just assuming it's Ethernet because it uses Ethernet connectors.  And that would be the easiest to implement.)

The receive module converts the Ethernet to a 4-port high speed USB hub.  The hub is a separate chip.

Comment: It is highly unlikely it converts USB to Ethernet. It just uses direct connection over same standard infrastructure cabling and same 8p8c connectors.

Comment: Could be, if it's an ASIC.  In fact, the silkscreen on the boards say "UTP", not "Ethernet", though there's not much room for that.  But the only off the shelf chips I could find were Ethernet.  E.g. https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/maxlinear-inc/XR22800IL32-F/4965569

Comment: that chip in the link is a standard component how to add a standard Ethernet port to a PC via USB, which is a completely different concept from extending USB beyond its rated specs transparently.